# FadeIn/FadeOut Two backgrounds for website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found one really nice thing on themeforest. However I am not interested in anything but that jquery background shuffle.

http://themeforest.net/item/launch-pad-full-screen-image-under-construction/full_screen_preview/473421

I thought to buy it but then I've noticed that guy put all scripts into one .js so I wouldnt understand quite mutch to remove all of these.

However... I was wondering if anyone can help me to make something like that without any of the options like on preview website.

I just want to have this fadeIn, fadeOut effect and two images to shuffle between 6 seconds. Sounds quite easy to make, but not without knowledge.

I will keep searching if something like that exists, thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Anyone who could make this kind of slider or any plugin that already exists?

Comment: You need the background image to fade from one pic to another?

Comment: Basically need to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UbmS9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fade-in feature of JQuery is documented here:
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

I would do it like that:

1. create the new image
2. hide it using JQuery .hide
3. insert it into the document at the exact same position as the old image, so that it is above it.
4. call .fadeIn on the new image
5. in the callback routine which I passed to .fadeIn I remove the image underneath so that the images don't stack indefinitely and eat up the browsers resources

Answer (score 0):

this is an old answer, but for someone looking for it nowdays, you can try the bgshuffle script. It uses JqueryUI. You will have to include JqueryUI somewhere in your page. The script is posted on github, feel free to expand it if you like:

https://github.com/vikaskumarsingh123/bgshuffle/

**You can simply call it like**:

```
shuffleBG( ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'] );//the array of wallpapers
```

**or Advanced Usage:**

```
shuffleBG(['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'], //the array of wallpapers
        '10000', //time between wallpaper change, defaults to 10000ms (10secs)
        '1000', //fade in fade out animation speed, defaults to 1000ms
        'white' //color to fade in and out of, defaults to body backgroundColor or white
);
```

You will usually be calling this function on document.load.